# Javascript 360 degrees panorama

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'm looking for a way to create a panorama view with a 360 degrees photo. I need a solution to do create something like QTVR. There is a lot flash based software out there (I'm trying to avoid that) and also some javascript/prototype/jquery solutions. But none of the solutions I've found have the behaviour I'm looking for. I want to eanable users to look around (just horizontal). Furniture objects on the pictures should react on mouseover, so that I might have multiple "layers" to distort. Is there a way to manipulate images in pure javascript or with jquery so, that it looks like they where bent cylindrical? Or does anyone know good libraries that support that kind of image manipulation? Might webgl be a good solution? I don't really know how to start. Is there anyone who could give me a hint. I'm just looking for a direction. google didn't bring me usable results.

Comment: Did you Google "javascript panorama"?  http://code.google.com/p/jspanoviewer/

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer. I've seen that. I was hoping for something differnt than slicing up the image.

Answer (score 5):

Check out three.js

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/webgl_panorama_equirectangular.html

Also, you could possibly do some of the image manipulation via canvas.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Pixel_manipulation_with_canvas

It might be easier (with canvas) to just have a fully processed panoramic image, and figure out which pixels represent your interactive object. Then listen for mouseovers on those pixels.

Answer (score 1):

try out http://panorado.com/en/PanoradoJs.php

There you'll find an excellent HTML5/JS based Viewer.

Comment: Note that this one is only free for non-commercial sites

Answer (score -1):

There are lots of tool to do that. Have you tried [www.vtility.net](http://www.vtility.net) ? Im not sure if it had mouse over layering. But it was the only SEO friendly that I have found.

Comment: I could not even figure out where to download their software or locate documentation on how to use it. This does not look like a good solution, nor is it customizable.

Comment: Hi Scott maybe this one is better for you since you want to download it: https://github.com/nicekei/jQuery-html5-canvas-panorama-plugin

Comment: Thanks for replying, I actually ended up going with [jQuery.cyclotron](https://github.com/mahonnaise/cyclotron). My main criteria for doing so were licensing(could not be GPL due to proprietary nature of my project) and ease of use(requires a line of JS and two or three lines of CSS). From a performance standpoint, there are much better options - this one works by breaking down the image into a bunch of divs, but it worked pretty well.

Comment: The last one does not need to download anything. Its an online tool. For how to use it I found this two:  [how to create videos] (http://www.vtility.net/howtocreatevirtualtour)   and [jsfiddle embed sample] (https://jsfiddle.net/wk65zyk8/1/)

Comment: I somehow did not realize that when I was first visiting the site, thank you for clarifying that. It looks like a really cool utility. My main challenge was that I already have image files for hundreds of panoramas that I need to render, and more can be added at any time. I am sure there is a way I could automate the Vtility program to create them all for me, but throwing together some Javascript is how we rolled :)

Comment: something like this: http://www.matthew25ministries.org/content/matthew-25-ministries-virtual-tour Also ddpanoram have an amazing sample https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1791448/ddpanorama/sample.interactive.html

Comment: I am impressed with ddpanorama, do you know which types of panoramic projections it can handle? Our images are cylindrical panoramas which means the file itself is a wide rectangular surface - it creates the panorama as if you were wrapping the image around a soda can. I wish more libraries specified that as I was not aware of the different types of panoramas and their limits. See [here](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/image-projections.htm) for more info on the types of panoramas and their unique features

Comment: cool read. Sadly not much work has been done for this in ddpanorama yet.